# is there any way to use compiled 32 bit native library as 64 bit lib

Tags: android, android-ndk, .so

I'm trying to publish my old android application on Play Store and facing issues with 64-bit native lib requirements.

So I have my Android Studio project written in Java and it does have one native library called libgba.so under armeabi. As you may already that Google play don't accept APKs that doesn't have x64 libraries. My project only have 32 bit compiled the native library. I don't have native code, unfortunately, to build the lib again.

APK is running just fine on all devices with the given 32-bit native lib but when I create and paste that 32-bit lib in the abi folder for x64 (arm64-v8a) under jniLibs I get an error like following when the library trying to load.

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.advanceDragon.superSaiyanGoku-2aOWxg51Zl-_I9XC0pDcwg==/lib/arm64/libgba.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit`

I want to know if there is any way to load lib under armeabi and also having lib under arm64-v8a but it should not get loaded (just for Google play's 64-bit requirement). Or if there any other options please suggest to me. Thanks.

**Edit: **

I tried using `System.load` to load .so lib from it's absolute path but I don't know where it exactly stored.

`String path = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/lib/";
        System.load(path + "libgba.so");`

Comment: contact the developer who developed the native lib, there’s nothing much that you can do, afaik.

Comment: If the device is running on x86, an arm library will not work-  the ISA is totally different.  A 32 bit x86 may work, as the 64 bit ISA is a superset of the 32.  You can try packaging the same lib in both places.  But you're better off just recompiling as 64 bit.  If its from a library, recompile the library from source.  If you're licensing the library and don't have source, talk to your vendor.

Comment: Native lib developer isn't available. That's why I'm seeking some help on stackoverflow

Comment: Where did you get the library from? If it really can't be rebuilt then you need to replace the library.

Comment: I got that library from  company called Liquid Mobile who have already built the app called a Gba (Gameboy Advance emulator). Now they're not available. Not able to contact even.

Comment: Can I actually point the lib under armeabi (that's working) and also having lib under arm64-v8a (left unused)? Is there any way to load like that?

Answer (score -2):

remove the 32 bit library from the 64 bit folder and just leave it in the 32 bit lib folder